# Laravel 8 Notifications markdown email template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm migrating over to the Laravel [Notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#introduction) because of the flexibility of having different channels. I'm migrating from the standard Laravel [Mail](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail) functionality.

With the existing functionality I have, I'm using custom markdown email templates and am returning them inside the `build` method of the individual mail classes that I've built, for instace...

```php
/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    $domain = isset($this->emailData[0]['domain']) ? $this->emailData[0]['domain'] : '';
    $domain = htmlspecialchars($domain);

    return $this->markdown('emails.domains.expiry')
                ->subject(isset($domain) && !empty($domain) ? "Domain Expiry Alert: $domain" : 'Domain Expiry Alert');
}
```

Doing it this way I can customise my various email templates.

Unortuantly, I tried this approach for the `toMail` method of my notification class variant, and it doesn't seem like Laravel Notifications support markdown files?

```php
/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $domain = isset($this->emailData[0]['domain']) ? $this->emailData[0]['domain'] : '';
    $domain = htmlspecialchars($domain);

    return $this->markdown('emails.domains.expiry')
                ->subject(isset($domain) && !empty($domain) ? "Domain Expiry Alert: $domain" : 'Domain Expiry Alert');
}
```

Instead, they're **expecting** the following...

```php
/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}
```

There is a section for customising templates, but this is the generic template and doesn't provide me with individual templates that I can pass data to. For instance, I need to pass a `$emailData` array to my template.

How can I get the `toMail` method to work with the Laravel Mail notification classes I've built?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a `MailMessage` from the `toMail` function. To send markdown emails from your notifications, modify your `toMail` function as follows:

```php
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
  $domain = isset($this->emailData[0]['domain']) ? $this->emailData[0]['domain'] : '';
  $domain = htmlspecialchars($domain);

  return (new MailMessage)
          ->subject(isset($domain) && !empty($domain) ? "Domain Expiry Alert: $domain" : 'Domain Expiry Alert')
          ->markdown('emails.domains.expiry');
}
```

Reference: [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#markdown-mail-notifications)

Comment: Thanks for that! Completely missed that part of the docs!